# Is there a ctrl-click through to resource bundles in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

If I have a Java source file open in Eclipse I want to be able to click on a resource bundle key to open the resource bundle at the associated line for editing. For example if I had a bundle `Bundle_en.properties`:

```
key1=Value One
key2=Value Two
```

And a source file:

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Bundle", Locale.ENGLISH);
String value = bundle.getString("key1");
```

I would like to be able to ctrl-click on that `"key1"` in the source file and have the properties file open up with key1 highlighted. In a real world scenario I would have a dozen properties files each containing hundreds of keys accessed from 20 different classes. Any pointers appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised you can't just ***CTRL+click*** the variable in the getString method.

I tested this in Eclipse *3.4.1*

1) create a class containing:

```
private static final String FOO = "bar";
```

2) right click FOO and select Source -> Externalize Strings

3) select the defaults and you'll end up with a messages.properties file and a Messages class that contains the ResourceBundle referencing code linking FOO to the value in messages.properties.

Once it's created FOO will look like:

```
static final String FOO=Messages.getString("Utils.0"); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

When I ***CTRL+click*** on "Utils.0" it takes me directly to the property in the resource bundle.

Comment: I don't know how/why this would be different from hand-written ResourceBundle accessing code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure eclipse provide this feature in a *direct* way.

However, you should be able to test your language packs associated with your plugin with an eclipse tool like **[Babel](http://www.eclipse.org/babel)**.

See how [JBoss does it](http://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-13256/diff%3Bjsessionid=7CE0025933D15C5F218E9FAC35DF4684?secondVersionNumber=4).

[image]
<sub>(source: [jboss.org](http://www.jboss.org/community/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/102-13256-4-1130/JBDS-pseudo.png))</sub>